# Setting feature attribute by name via QGIS python api?

Tags: pyqgis

I try to set feature attributes by attribute name with this code

```
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("test", QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
 attrName = 'test'
 feature[attrName] = 1
```

but in result I have NULL in all fields. 
If I use

```
feature.setAttributes([1])
```

it works properly.

What I do wrong? Why feature[attrName] = 1 doesn't work?

**Update**:
Find this solution

```
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("test", QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
 attrName = 'test'
 feature[attrName] = 1
 pr.changeAttributeValues({feature.id() : {pr.fieldNameMap()[attrName] : 1}})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

QGIS can use field names and indexes:

```
feature['fieldname'] = 10
feature[1] = 10
```

Make sure you are in edit mode before you do anything on the layer:

```
layer.startEditing()
feature['fieldname'] = 10
layer.updateFeature(feature)

#Call commit to save the changes
layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, QGIS uses field indexes, not field names, for assignment. Try using `feature[layer.fieldNameIndex(attrName)] = 1`.

Comment: I try: `feature.setAttribute(attrName, 1)` and `feature.setAttribute(layer.fieldNameIndex(attrName), 1)` with same results (api reference have two setAttribute methods for feature with index and name)

Comment: `feature[layer.fieldNameIndex(attrName)] = 1` also the same.

Comment: Have you initialised the attributes (`feature.initAttributes(len(attributes))`)?

Comment: Add `feature.initAttributes(1)` with same result. But check `feature[attrName]` and got 1 which I looking for. But still have NULL if I open Attribute Table in gui.