# Filling layer attributes field from Python list using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a QGIS3 layer which has an attribute column indicating the id of each features. I want to add two more fields and fill them with some values ​​taken from a python list.

The list is something like that:

```
l = [['1', 'something', 'something else']]
```

where '1' is the id of the feature and 'something' and 'something else' are the values ​​that must fill the column in correspondence with the right id.

```
    data_provider = layer.dataProvider()
    data_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('field1',  QVariant.String)])
    data_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('field2',  QVariant.String)])
    layer.updateFields()
    l = [['1', 'something', 'something else'],['2', 'something', 'something else']]
```

I tried in this way:

```
mem_layer.startEditing()
for feat in mem_layer.getFeatures(): 
    for i in l:
        if str(feat["id"])==i[0]:
            feat.setFields(feat.fields(),True)
            feat.setAttribute('field1', i[1])
            feat.setAttribute('field2', i[2])
mem_layer.commitChanges()
```

But nothing changed. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correction. Code mainly borrowed from [Setting feature attribute by name via QGIS python api?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83641/setting-feature-attribute-by-name-via-qgis-python-api) answer

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # I select the layer I want to modify, not needed for your case normally
data_provider = layer.dataProvider()
data_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('field1',  QVariant.String)])
data_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('field2',  QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
l = [['1', 'something', 'something else'],['2', 'something', 'something else']]

layer.startEditing()
for feat in layer.getFeatures(): 
    for i in l:
        if str(feat["id"])==i[0]:
            feat['field1'] = i[1] # modification here
            feat['field2'] = i[2] # modification here
            layer.updateFeature(feat) # modification here

layer.commitChanges()
```